# Chrome input type file width (click area)

Tags: html, css

```
#uploadImg{width:30px;}

<input type='file' id="uploadImg" />
```

I have an input type file, i change width to 30px, when i test on chrome, if i click right hand side (outside of 30px) the input file will still open. anyone know how to change the click area for input type file in chrome?

http://jsfiddle.net/smrB4/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add some css:

```
#uploadImg{width:30px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `overflow:hidden` attribute.

Also, it might be a good idea to style the file upload dialog itself because it will look different on every browser. Basically you need 'hide' the real file upload element and add custom styled element.

See an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/smrB4/3/

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='overlay'>
        X
    </div>
    <input type='file' id="uploadImg" />
</div>
<br>
<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8593;click here </span>
```

CSS:

```
#uploadImg{width:30px;opacity:0.0;}
#container{position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:30px;height:30px;}
#overlay{position:absolute;top:0p;width:28px;height:28px;background-color:#ddd;border:1px solid #000}
```